# Is the commentary of Rabbaynu Saadya Gaon on Iyov available online?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, job-iyov-book-of, saadya-gaon

I was not able to find the commentary of R' Saadya Gaon to Iyov on Hebrewbooks ([ex 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40229&st=&pgnum=153)), Sefaria or through a Google search. I would like to know if this commentary is available anywhere online, free or paid.

Comment: likely not helpful, maybe of intrest http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/messages/dmut_dmut_1292_0.html

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed.  The first 40 pages can be viewed for free, and the rest are behind a paywall at Otzar Hachochma.  There are various options for purchasing passes to use Otzar Hachochma (for various lengths of time for various prices) in [Hebrew](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/pcionlinestore.aspx) or [English](https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/pcionlinestoreeng.aspx?lang=eng), as well as the printing limits.

Here is the url: https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?24835

Answer (score -1):

You can purchase a physical copy of the sefer [here](http://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Saadia-Gaon---IYOV__p-6095.aspx). It includes the text in the original Arabic (written in Hebrew characters of course) plus the translation into Hebrew by [Rabbi Yosef Kapach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih).

Comment: I don't think that is what the question was asking for... :(

Comment: @רבותמחשבות _"I would like to know if this commentary is available anywhere online, free or paid."_

Comment: I understood "online" to be as opposed to in print.